# Joomla after SEF " Page Not Found " 404 Error?

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, joomla, http-status-code-404

I am trying to open URL of article from Facebook page on my website but the problem is every time *error 404* is raised although the article is exists .

After searching I find that there is problem in `.htaccess` codes and I need help in this.

**The problem :**

URL : [like from facebook page](http://www.businesstendersmag.com/component/content/article/134-arabic/%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B6%D8%A9/3931-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%87-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8B%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A9)

Website : worked like [Real link](http://www.businesstendersmag.com/ar/%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%87/3931-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%87-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8B%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A9)

As you can see there different between this two links.

The part is added "**component/content/**" and without the another language prefix "**ar**".

**Some Details :**

This is my `.htaccess` file :

```
> ##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
# Forward to sitemap
Redirect /sitemap.xml http://www.businesstendersmag.com/ar/?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=3
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

That's all! Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate URLs that are posted to Facebook?

Are you generating URLs like this?

```
// require com_content router.
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
// generate link.
$link = JURI::root() . substr( JRoute::_( ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute( $article->slug, $article->categorySlug ) ), strlen(JURI::base(true)) + 1);
// Where $article->slug  & $article->categorySlug are fetched from database.
```

Comment: I am using Plugin to autopublish the article it's called "Facebook - Twitter - Google+1 plugin" and this one "jvsocial publish" the two give me the same problems

Comment: i check one i find this code : 'require_once(JPATH_SITE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_content' . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'route.php');'

Comment: when am try to remove the "/components/com_content" the website crashed

Comment: From which line of code did you remove this "/components/com_content" ? If removing that makes the file path invalid, it will show error. Well, it looks like the plugin/component you using the com_content's router, but it might not be passing all the required URL parts when generating URL being posted. Try contacting the plugin/component developer.